# How to call a stored procedure with in and out parameters using mysql prepare and execute statement?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I know this code does not work!!!
But need a code which will work in this approach.

```
SET @sp_name = "sp_user";
SET @response = "";
SET @sp_call = CONCAT('CALL ',@sp_name,'(',@request,',@response)');
PREPARE STMT from @sp_call;
EXECUTE STMT;
SELECT @response;
```

response is out parameter

Thanks

Comment: Post FULL code, not a part of it. Local variable `response` must be defined - show this. Or use user-defined variable instead.

Answer (score 1):

An example:

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE sp_user (IN arg1 TEXT, OUT arg2 TEXT)
> BEGIN
>     IF arg1 = 'abc' THEN
>         SET arg2 = 'abc provided';
>     ELSE
>         SET arg2 = 'Something else provided';
>     END IF;
> END
> ```

> ```
> SET @sp_name = 'sp_user';
> SET @request = '\'abc\'';
> SET @sp_call = CONCAT('CALL ',@sp_name,'(',@request,',@response)');
> SELECT @sp_call;
> PREPARE STMT from @sp_call;
> EXECUTE STMT;
> SELECT @response;
> ```
>
> ```
> | @sp_call                      |
> | :---------------------------- |
> | CALL sp_user('abc',@response) |
>
> | @response    |
> | :----------- |
> | abc provided |
> ```

> ```
> SET @sp_name = 'sp_user';
> SET @request = '\'def\'';
> SET @sp_call = CONCAT('CALL ',@sp_name,'(',@request,',@response)');
> SELECT @sp_call;
> PREPARE STMT from @sp_call;
> EXECUTE STMT;
> SELECT @response;
> ```
>
> ```
> | @sp_call                      |
> | :---------------------------- |
> | CALL sp_user('def',@response) |
>
> | @response               |
> | :---------------------- |
> | Something else provided |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=182324220300f82aea9b73f3936a1b8f)*